# Mongodb converts timestamps to dates with a value of NaN

Tags: mongodb

In mongodb 4.4, a strange thing happened when $convert was used in mongodb to convert a double value to a date type, and onError did not take effect when the value was negative
-202636829548800000, onError is not valid,
-39176725729017600000 indicates that onError takes effect

An attempt was made to use $ifNull in $convert, but $convert onNull was detected when the field query was processed and then the field value NaN was converted

In this case, what should I do with the NaN value

### 查询示例

```
aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "testNumber1_default": {
            "$convert": {
              "input": {
                "$subtract": [
                  {
                    "$add": [NumberLong("1708617600000"),2*24*60*60000
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    "$multiply": [2345353453,24*60*60000]
                  }
                ]
              },
              "to": "date",
              "onError": null,
              "onNull": null,
            }
      },
      "testNumber1_double": {
        "$convert": {
          "input": {
            "$subtract": [
              {
                "$add": [Double("1708617600000"),2*24*60*60000
                ]
              },
              {
                "$multiply": [2345353453,24*60*60000]
              }
            ]
          },
          "to": "double",
          "onError": null,
          "onNull": null
        }
      },
      "testNumber1_date": {
       "$convert": {
          "input": "$testNumber1_double",
          "to": "date",
          "onError": null,
          "onNull": null
        }
      },
      "testNumber2_double": {
       "$convert": {
          "input": {
            "$subtract": [
              {
                "$add": [Double("1708617600000"),2*24*60*60000
                ]
              },
              {
                "$multiply": [453434345345,24*60*60000]
              }
            ]
          },
          "to": "double",
          "onError": null,
          "onNull": null
        }
      },
      "testNumber2_date": {
       "$convert": {
          "input": "$testNumber2_double",
          "to": "date",
          "onError": null,
          "onNull": null
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
      "$project":{
          "testNumber1_default":1,
          "testNumber1_double":1,
          "testNumber1_date":1,
          "testNumber2_double":1,
          "testNumber2_date":1,
      }
  },
  {
    "$skip": 0
  },
  {
    "$limit": 1
  }
])
```

### 查询结果

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7oAl.png)

Attempted to use $ifnull in $convert, but when querying the field first and then converting the field value NaN, it was detected that $convert onnull was effective

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg2vb.png)

Conversion failed, type is still double instead of null or date

Comment: Maybe a stupid question: why do you not store proper `Date` objects?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Because this field is dynamic, the date value or numerical value will be calculated based on the formula

Comment: The question remains. You can do calculations also on date values. And why should it make any difference whether the field is dynamic (whatever this means) or not?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit It means one more step of calculation, which can be ignored in most cases. So, if it doesn't work, there can be multiple stages. But that's not what I want. I want to figure out why it's NaN instead of null

Comment: First of all, please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors Second, your pipeline does not make much sense. You cannot use fields (e.g. `$testNumber1_double`) which are added in the same stage. Either use another `$set` stage or use `$let`. Are you aware of the [Date Expression Operators](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#date-expression-operators)?

Answer (score 0):

In deed, looks like if you try to convert number -202636829548800000 into a `Date` then you get an `Invalid Date` error, whereas -39176725729017600000 returns a `null`.

```
[
  {
    input: -202636829548800000,
    type: 'double',
    testNumber1_default: Invalid Date,
    testNumber1_double: -202636829548800000
  },
  {
    input: -39176725729017600000,
    type: 'double',
    testNumber1_default: null,
    testNumber1_double: -39176725729017600000
  }
]
```

However, the valid number range which can be converted into a `Date` is ±8'640'000'000'000'000. This is the range from April 20, 271'821 BC to September 13, 275'760 AD.

Whenever your application returns a value of -39176725729017600000 or -202636829548800000 which shall be converted to a `Date`, then you have definitively a problem with your application! And it would be a even stronger reason to store values properly as `Date` object instead of numbers.

Comment: Thank you, that's all for the business. I also feel helpless. Thank you for your reply